# Método de extensión no retorna los datos

Tags: c#

Estoy tratando de hacer un método de extensión que permita cargar una lista de objetos desde un fichero json, para ello tengo el siguiente método:

```
    public static void LoadFromJsonFile<T>(this List<T> list, string file) where T : class
    {
        if (File.Exists(file))
        {
            String JSONtxt = File.ReadAllText(file);
            
            list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(JSONtxt);
        }
    }
```

Al realizar la llamada mi lista de objetos se mantiene vacía:

```
    personas = new List<Persona>();

    personas.LoadFromJsonFile(@"c:\personas.json");
```

No sé si estoy equivocado pero yo entiendo que no debería ser necesario retornar nada en el método extensor ya que el parámetro *list* que recibe se comporta como un paso por referencia.

En cualquier caso, he probado con los cambios siguientes:

```
    public static List<T> LoadFromJsonFile<T>(this List<T> list, string file) where T : class
    {
        if (File.Exists(file))
        {
            String JSONtxt = File.ReadAllText(file);
            
            list = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(JSONtxt);

            return list;
        }
    }
```

Modificando la llamada:

```
    personas = new List<Persona>();

    personas = personas.LoadFromJsonFile(@"c:\personas.json");
```

Y funciona, pero no veo ningún sentido a tener que hacerlo así.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, el primer parámetro de un **método extensor** se usa solamente para indicar cual es el tipo de datos que vas a extender.

Los **métodos extensores** se introdujeron a partir de **C# 3.0** para permitir la incorporación de nuevas funcionalidades en tipos existentes. Son **métodos estáticos** definidos dentro de una **clase estática** y cuyo primer parámetro va precedido por la **palabra clave this**, indicando que este es el tipo que se quiere extender.

Atendiendo a tu ejemplo y como ya tú mismo dices, la forma correcta de crear tu **método extensor** sería:

```
public static class Extensores
{
    public static List<T> LoadFromJsonFile<T>(this List<T> list, string file) where T : class
    {
        if (File.Exists(file))
        {
            String JSONtxt = File.ReadAllText(file);           
            return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(JSONtxt);
        }
    }
}
```

Y lo usarías de esta forma:

```
var personas = personas.LoadFromJsonFile(@"c:\personas.json");
```

Cabe destacar que aunque pareciera que el **método extensor** se ha definido dentro de la propia clase, no es más que **azúcar sintáctica** para llamar a un **método estático**, que puede invocarse de la forma habitual con el mismo resultado:

```
var personas = Extensores.LoadFromJsonFile(@"c:\personas.json");
```

Un ejemplo donde se usan los **métodos extensores** es en **Linq**, los empleamos cuando usamos métodos como **Where**, **Select**, **OrderBy**, etcétera.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aclaracion. Esa era mi duda, si realmente habia que hacer uso de el como si llamaramos a una clase cualquiera en la que estuviera definido.

Answer (score 0):

Tu método es `static` lo que significa que se llama desde la clase no desde la instancia

```
personas = new List<Persona>();

Persona.LoadFromJsonFile(personas, @"c:\personas.json");
```

además, `personas` es una lista de tipo `Persona`, tu llamada inicial no debiese ser posible, no se que IDE estas usando para desarrollar pero te aconsejo instalar un inellisense de c#

Comment: Agradezco tu comentario. Estoy utilizando VS Community y la llamada es posible. Lo que no es posible es Persona.LoadFromJsonFile(personas, @"c:\personas.json"); ya que mi clase Persona y el metodo extensor no tienen nada que ver.

Comment: no había visto la parte de extension methods, y si, no necesita el return, haz debugeado algo? entra al if? efectivamente ese JSONTxt tiene algo? puede leer el archivo?

Comment: el fichero existe y tiene contenido valido, de hecho si se depura el metodo, tras la asignacion del contenido del fichero, list contiene el numero de elementos que hay en el fichero, pero ese contenido es el que no se refleja en la lista de personas, de ahi mi duda